# command to remove specific string from multiple files

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a directory `dash7/` which contains multiple text files and I want to remove all lines containing the string `D PRINT` from all those files.

How can I do that easily from the command-line?

Comment: thanks.i have used "find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i /KeyWord/d" and its working.thank you.

Comment: @KISHAN Would you please consider writing an answer to your own question, so that future readers will be able to easily profit from what you found out? Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You can achieve this rather easily with `sed` which can happily look into multiple files

```
sed '/D PRINT/d' dash7/*
```

- `/D PRINT/` find a line with `D PRINT`
- `d` delete the line
- `dash7/*` look in all the files in the directory `dash7` (add the path to it, for example `~/dash7` if required)

To actually change the files rather than print the edited text in the terminal, you need to add the `-i` flag to modify in place

```
sed -i '/D PRINT/d' dash7/*
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion,i hv used " find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i /KeyWord/d" and its working.thank you.

Comment: @KISHAN yes you mentioned that, but I added my answer to help others. You can also help others by posting your solution as an answer to your question instead of a comment :)